# Tableau TabPy extension with a Python Anywhere account

Tags: python, pythonanywhere, tableau-desktop, tabpy

Does anybody had successfully configured Tableau Desktop to use PythonAnywhere as an external service where to execute python scripts with Tableau?

I am trying to follow [this tutorial](https://www.theinformationlab.co.uk/2019/04/09/how-to-set-up-tabpy-in-tableau/) but it is about using a `localhost` server, so it looks different from using a cloud solution like PA and I don't know what to write in the `External Services` fields.

- What are the server name and the port?
- Need I to use an SSL connection?

[image]

Comment: Do you mean running TabPy server on PythonAnywhere? You would not be able to do that, as users can't open ports there. Only WSGI web apps are visible to the outside world.

Comment: OK, thanks @Filip ! Do you know the name of any cloud service where I could run python and install a running version of TabPy?

Comment: I've found it, I will use AWS EC2 and install TabPy on a free tier https://www.simboli.eu/p.php?URL_short=CONFIGURE_AWS_EC2_PYTHON_TABLEAU